# Get permission to do PTRACE_ATTACH

Tags: ptrace

I'm trying to write a program to do `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, nullptr, nullptr)` but it returns `-1` and errno is `3` (No such process). The tracee are running and kicked off by me so I guess the tracer should have permission. What should I do then?

Also ptrace seems to be on per-thread basis. Is there easy way to get all the thread ids given a process id? Only way is to check `/proc/{pid}/task/{tid}`? How to catch thread creation?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch thread creation using `ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, nullptr, PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE)`. I'd suggest carefully reading `man 2 ptrace`.

`PTRACE_ATTACH` might fail for numerous reasons. Try running your process as root with `sudo`.